flutter stuck at "Installing profile for com.example.learn_flut"
it has been like 30 mins and while running the app I'm always stuck at "Installing profile for com.example.learn_flut".
the problem is the app just shows the flutter logo and is stuck at "Installing profie" its not progressing further.
is my code causing any problem or what?
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

I tried multiple time restarting and flutter clean, pub get but it seems to not work.
I was using an emulator but after running it on my phone also it is stuck at "Installing profile".
what could be the reason for this?
also someone suggested that i should provide more info, what should i info should i provide more?image this where i am stuck at.

Did you solve the problem?

Have you find a solution yet?

@LoukasPap I found the solution check it out below.

@EmirhanSelimUzun I'll see it.
